# compare two files from an arbitrary line in Perl

Tags: perl, compare

I know that one can compare two files in Perl using:

```
 use strict; 
 use warnings;
 use File::Compare;

 my $file1 = "example1.txt";
 my $file2 = "Test_2.txt";

 if (compare($file1,$file2) eq 0) 
 {
    print "They're equal\n";
 }else{
    print "They aren't equal\n";
 }
```

Well, I am interested to know if one can compare files from a desired line. I have huge files and after a fixed line number maybe they are different. It takes very long time to compare the whole files. Then I am looking for a shortest way!

Comment: It's actually quite hard to 'skip' a bunch of lines on the file - you effectively have to read it that far, because you don't know how long the lines are. 
You could fake it a bit via `seek` but that lets you skip a number of _bytes_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. `compare` accepts file handles as well as file names, so you can just open the files and read past the lines you want to ignore before you call `compare`

This example code just ignores the first line from both files. I hope you understand how to skip a given number of lines, or until a regex pattern matches?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Compare 'compare';

open my $fh1, '<', 'file1.txt';
open my $fh2, '<', 'file2.txt';

# read past header lines
<$fh1>; 
<$fh2>;

if ( compare( $fh1, $fh2 ) eq 0 ) {
    print "They're equal\n";
}
else {
    print "They aren't equal\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the region of interest is after a line that starts with the string `BEGIN`. You can simply discard all lines from both files until you hit the marker. Doing so, you avoid the cost of the `compare` function, but you must still pay the IO cost.

```
$_ = <$fh1> until /^BEGIN/;
$_ = <$fh2> until /^BEGIN/;
```

If you have some *a priori* information, for example, the region never begins within the first ten megabytes of the file, you can `seek` there first.